# Issue in self join : Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

**Database Table Schema**

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('tblrole')) {
    Schema::create('tblrole', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('RoleID')->autoIncrement();
        $table->unsignedInteger('ParentRoleID')->nullable();
        $table->string('Role', 25)->unique();

        $table->boolean("IsActive")->default(0);

        $table->foreign('ParentRoleID')->references('RoleID')->on('tblrole');

    });
}
```

**Eloquent Model**

```
class RoleModel extends Model
{
    public $table = 'tblrole';
    public $primaryKey = 'RoleID';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'IsActive'  =>  'boolean'
    ];

    public function ParentRole() {
        return $this->hasOne("App\Models\User\Role\RoleModel", "RoleID", "ParentRoleID");
    }
}
```

**Query not working**

```
$Roles = RoleModel
    ::select("RoleID", "Role", "IsActive")
    ->with(["ParentRole" => function($query) {
        $query->select("RoleID", 'Role', "IsActive");
    }])
    ->get();
```

**Working Query**

```
$Roles = RoleModel->with("ParentRole")->get();
```

**Problem**

In the above not working query, ParentRole is always null.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: `with` is not used for joins, it's used for eager loading (which issues a 2nd query instead of creating a single query with a join statement). I've also never seen anyone use `select` in a call to eloquent (Model.get is used to specify which columns you want to select) as it's used typically when using the DB facade and building raw sql queries with the query builder..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you explicitly exclude the `ParentRoleID` from the query, eloquent doesn't know its value and can't make the connection to the parent role. Try adding `ParentRoleID` to your `select()` or remove the `select()` altogether.

```
$Roles = RoleModel
::select("RoleID", "Role", "IsActive", "ParentRoleID")
->with(["ParentRole" => function($query) {
    $query->select("RoleID", 'Role', "IsActive");
}])
->get();
```